# Advice on setting up a marketplace app in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I want to create a marketplace app which displays a different user flow (UI UX) when a customer or seller logs in. How can i achieve this with React Native?

Is this classed as a multi tenant app?

As an absolute beginner, i would appreciate some advice and possibly links to documentation on how to set up the structure using Visual Studio Code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Create a different set of routes for both seller and customer via route authorization.

Answer (score 0):

You can use state management such as mobx or redux,set seller or customer on launch,so every screen or component can request at any time if wether a seller or customer then render the right things

Answer (score 0):

As someone mentioned, redux or different routes after authorization might be what you want.  But it sounds like you may have bigger picture issues/questions.  The front end could certainly be written in react native, but you need a back-end where the data will live and users will be authorized.  If you don't want to write that yourself, you might consider [Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/), as its easy to use and free up to a certain usage level.

Firebase handles authorization easily; then when people are creating accounts, have them specify if they're sellers, etc, and save that to user profiles.  When they log in, use the data in their user profile to direct them to different react navigation stacks or just different themes or whatever your needs are.